# How tot find Proportion of people who know at least 2 languages

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

We have a csv file
For each computer programming knowledge level (ProgSkills), we need to find the proportion (0-1) of students who know at least one of JS and R languages, with Classification knowledge of at least 2.

CSV file

```
ProgSkills        JS     R         Classification
    4             1.0   1.0              4
    3             0.0   1.0              2
    2             0.0   0.0              3
    4             1.0   1.0              2
    5             1.0   0.0              1
    1             1.0   1.0              1
    2             0.0   0.0              4
```

There are other columns but these are the ones tht it is needed for this problem
My approach (its currently in 2 separate columns but its not what we want):

```
df.loc[df['Classification']>=2].groupby('ProgSkills')[['Python','Java']].mean()
```

My question: Is there a way to find the proportion of students who know JS and R w the classification of at least 2? I'm not sure how to "combine" the 2 programming columns to account for the "at least" part.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the proportion of each possibility for knowing or not `JS` and `R` by using something like:

```
df.groupby(['JS', 'R']).apply(len) / len(df.index)
```

Which will return

```
JS   R  
0.0  0.0    0.285714
     1.0    0.142857
1.0  0.0    0.142857
     1.0    0.428571
```

If you want just the proportion of those who know *at least* one of the programming languages, than you can filter the original dataframe by removing those who doesn't know both of them. This can be achieved by something like this:

```
prog_filter = ~((df['JS'] == 0) & (df['R'] == 0))
proportion = len(df[prog_filter].index) / len(df.index)
print(proportion)  # output: 0.7142857142857143
```

Comment: Do you know what "at least one of ___ and ___" mean? The way you suggested makes sense, but im not sure of the wording.

Comment: Since you have just two variables `JS` and `R`, you have 4 possibilities: either the student knows `JS` but doesn't know `R`, either the student knows `R` but doesn't know `JS`, either the student knows both or doesn't know either of them. In your case you want **at least** one of the variables to be True, which left the only "non-desireable" combination to be `(JS == 0) & (R == 0)`. Once you logically negate this sentence, you get your desireable logic filter for the dataframe.